# Would secure boot block GPU if it has modified vbios?

Tags: windows, bios, uefi, secure-boot, gpu

I think that AMD GPUs can be flashed with any modded VBIOS because the GPU doesn't check for firmware signature.

Shouldn't the secure boot be able to check signature of the AMD GPUs modded VBIOS and block the PC from booting if the signature is invalid?

Can people who have modified their AMD GPU's VBIOS boot into Windows if secure boot is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

No. Secure boot checks that the boot process hasn't been tampered with, but it neither knows nor cares about any firmware except that in the motherboard (the UEFI / "BIOS"). There aren't actually a lot of checks that the secure boot can do which allow normal system maintenance (such as installing a new driver, which might install new firmware on internal or peripheral devices) without risk of making your machine unbootable.

The primary thing that secure boot does do is verify the chain of CPU execution from power-on until the OS starts. The TPM verifies that the board firmware is trusted. The board firmware verifies that the bootloader is trusted. The bootloader verifies that the kernel is trusted. The kernel verifies that the drivers are trusted... and then you have a booted system, and Secure Boot isn't really doing much anymore.

The GPU (and any other processors on the graphics card) isn't a part of this process, any more than the microcontrollers on your network interface or your SSD or your USB ports are.

*EDIT: As @Ben Voigt pointed out in the comments, the video driver could verify the VBIOS - or overwrite it - if it was written to do so. While this isn't part of secure boot per se, if the video driver has such a feature then you should be able to trust the VBIOS as the driver can't be modified without tampering with the kernel, which *is* verified by secure boot. However, if an older (but still officially signed) video driver lacked such verification, it would be possible to downgrade the driver and thus tamper with VBIOS undetectably without secure boot verification failing. Rollback prevention is generally implemented by the verifying layer - for the video driver, this would be the OS - and so far as I know, no mainstream OS routinely enforces rollback prevention for older signed drivers.*

Comment: Might mention that the chain does permit securing the VBIOS, as "secure boot verifies system firmware verifies bootloader verifies OS kernel verifies video driver verifies VBIOS"  It's a matter of whether the GPU vendor has placed that check in the driver (and because the driver is verified by the OS kernel, it can't be tampered with to remove such check)

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point, but it depends on the driver having such a check (and the OS not allowing an attacker to replace that driver with a different one - possibly an older, but still signed, one - that lacks the check, and since the check isn't mandated by secure boot, such a driver would likely exist. Still, a good point, and I've added it to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @BenVoigt But usually you have video output before the OS starts i.e. before you can even load any driver which checks the VBIOS. It would be verification after the VBIOS has been loaded and executed.

Comment: @secfren: I think we're running into the ambiguity of "VBIOS".  Historically, graphics chips had fixed-function pipeline and a ROM (often, EEPROM) chip holding an "extension BIOS" that the main system BIOS called during startup, which typically installed software interrupt/syscall handlers for BIOS video API.  But for modern PCs running EFI/UEFI firmware, extension BIOS is no longer a thing.  The firmware loads EFI-compliant video drivers, and like all EFI extension modules, those will be verified.  What's left in a modern VBIOS is code that executes on the GPU, not the system CPU.